# Unknown pattern extraction for C

Tags: c, signal-processing, extract

I'm currently developing an audio processing software that must detect the frequency of the incoming signal by use of Zero Crossing estimation. It's not difficult to estimate the frequency when a perfect sin wave is the input, but when speaking about a piano, the soundwave is different and the theory behind this changes.

At the moment the software detects every zero and saves the index location between it and the previous one (to record how many samples have gone by).

The following is an array that contains the samples between each zero for a 130 Hz piano C note sampled at 44.1kHz.

```
44  11  36  65  56  12  37  66  52  13  38  67  51  11  39  68  50  11  47  60  49  11  48  61  47  14  47  66  43  13
```

The task is to determine an unknown pattern of an unknown length. But, these patterns might have an error margin. For example,

```
44, 11, 36, 65
56, 12, 37, 66
52, 13, 38, 67
```

are patterns. So, after processing the pattern's mean sums the frequency can be easily detected.
**How can I detect these type of patterns, knowing that the pattern, as is, and the length of it is unknown.**

Comment: I would suggest that you **don't** use zero-crossing to estimate frequency...

Comment: Reminds me of [auto-correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation). Anyhow, you should be looking for [Pitch Detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm).

Comment: The microprocessor in which is implemented cannot run a FFT in real-time, that's why I'm using the ZeroX approach @OliCharlesworth

Comment: Oh, if you can't do FFT, auto-correlation won't work, because FFT is the most efficient way of calculating it. I think your chances of succeeding with a weak CPU are pretty slim.

Comment: You cannot find all frequencies like this, but you might be able to estimate the lowest one. If you have enough samples, you can try construct a 'spectrogram': for each pattern length plot it's occurrence count. Then form this find position of possible peak(s) in the spectrogram.

Comment: For your grouping into a set of vectors of length 4, try computing a distance metric between these vectors in the set.  Then repeat for groupings/sets of 2,6,8,etc., and pick the set with the lowest and most consistent distance metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try low-passing your signal first. This will reduce the signal components, including higher overtones which are leading to extra zero crossings. The point here is to increase the strength of the fundamental relative to other harmonics, which are effectively just creating extraneous zero crossings.

For some hints on EQ:

http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/08/basic-audio-eqs.html

and eq as it specifically pertains to pitch detection:

http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/07/frequency-detection-using-fft-aka-pitch.html

Depending on your signal, you may need something steeper, like a higher order or different kind of filter.

Of course, zeroX pitch detection will be inherently limited, and a low-pass may not be sufficient.

**Update**: clarified that the purpose of the low pass is to emphasize the fundamental, not to eliminate noise.

Comment: A low pass filter will only help if the fundamental frequency is the strongest spectral component of the musical note pitch.  For many musical instruments, including the piano, this isn't true for many notes.

Comment: Actually, that's not true. As long as the fundamental is present, it will be the lowest pitch, and therefore a lowpass filter strengthen the fundamental relative to the other partials, which is why I suggested it. I will edit my answer a bit to make this clearer.

Comment: @BjornRoche: Actually, *that's* not true (necessarily)!  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subharmonic

Comment: Subharmonics are the exception. If the OP asked about piano, for which this is a reasonable assumption.